# Backend api query works fine on localhost but IBM cloud code engine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, backend

I have a web app with react frontend and nodeJS backend with mongodb. By directly sending search request to backend API it works fine but when sending to the deployed one it just display all results.
This is the frontend API call with axios

```
      // search placements
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `${SERVER_URL}/api/placements/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}`
      );
```

This is the backend:

```
// Search placements
placementRouter.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  const searchQuery = decodeURI(req.query.q);
  console.log("searching for:", req.query.q);

  // If the search query is empty, return all placements
  if (searchQuery === "") {
    const placements = await Placement.find();
    return res.send(placements);
  }

  // Use a regular expression to search for matching placements
  const regex = new RegExp(searchQuery, "i");
  const placements = await Placement.find({
    $or: [
      { provider: regex },
      { placementType: regex },
      { animalType: regex },
      { address: regex },
      { county: regex },
      { postcode: regex },
      { country: regex },
      { contactName: regex },
      { positionAtPractice: regex },
      { email: regex },
      { phoneNumber: regex },
      { website: regex },
      { spaExpiry: regex },
      { notes: regex },
    ],
  });
  console.log("search results: ", placements);
  res.send(placements);
});
```

It works fine for all other request but this one

It should return results based on search, with `localhost:3001/api/placements/search?=alex` it just return result contains the word "alex", but when tried to do `<ibmcloud-code-engine-url>/api/placements/search?=alex` it just return all result without matching the word alex.